# How to handle a conditional operator w JavaScript+React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operators, ternary-operator

I have the following JavaScript:

```
const { inverseDirection } = this.props;
```

**if inverseDirection is false, I need the following:**

```
const dashOffset =
  dashArray - (dashArray * this.state.percentProgress) / 100;
```

**if inverseDirection is true, I need the following:**

```
const dashOffset =
  dashArray + (dashArray * this.state.percentProgress) / 100;
```

What is the right way to elegantly code this without duplication the entire line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
const dashOffset = inverseDirection 
? ( dashArray + (dashArray * this.state.percentProgress) / 100) 
: (dashArray - (dashArray * this.state.percentProgress) / 100)
```

Not really that elegant but anything more complex would be a waste of time and probably not very readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
const { inverse } = this.props;

let calc = (x, y) => (x * y) / 100

let offset = arr + (inverse ? -1 : 1)*(calc(arr, this.state.percentProgress))
```

This way you can extract/reuse the `calc` function (or move to `utils` etc) and the `inverse` operation boils down to a simply `inverse ? -1 : 1` which is what you are really after.